# How can i position those images over each other?

Tags: html, css, image, position, graphical-logo

I tried to position my logo and headerpic on top of each other like this:

```css
img {
    position: absolute;
    top: 25px;
    left: 25px;
}
.imgA1 {
    z-index: 1;
}
.imgB1 {
    z-index: 3;
}
```

```html
    <img class="imgA1" src="https://placehold.it/200/333333">
    <img class="imgB1" src="https://placehold.it/100">
```

But my logo is still at the top end of my header pic.

My css code looks like this:

```
.header img.headerpic  { 
    max-width:100%; 
    float:left; 
    position:relative;
    background:transparent url(../images/header.jpg)
}
.header img.logo { 
    position: relative; 
    float:left; 
    max-width:100%;  
    background:transparent url(../images/logo.png )
}
```

and i added this in my index.php:

```
<body id="home">

<!-- header area -->

    <div class="header">
        <id="logo">
            <img src="<?php echo TEMPLATE_DIR; ?>/images/logo.png" alt="logo"/>
            <img class="headerpic" src="<?php echo TEMPLATE_DIR; ?>/images/headspacer.jpg" alt="" />
        <div class="infobox"><div class="inner">    
    </div>
</body>
```

What do i need to change that my Header-Picture is the background and my logo is on the left in the center of the Picture?

[My actual view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6c5vA.png)

Comment: Why the first img into the div hasn't class?

Comment: @Jprada i don't know i aproved the edit hoping it was right.

EDIT: It disappears when i add:

     `<img class="logo" `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`position:absolute` is relative to the [nearest positioned parent, or the entire page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position#Absolute_positioning). Therefore, here you are setting the images to be at the exact same location.

What you need is for `.imgB1` to set `position: relative` and then move it to place with the `top` and others. E.g something like so:

```css
#logo img {
   position:absolute;  
}

.header img.headerpic  { 
    max-width:100%; 
    top: 10px;
    left: 10px;
    position: relative !important;
}
```

```html
    <div class="header" id="logo">
            <img src="https://placehold.it/200/333333" alt="logo"/>
            <img class="headerpic" src="https://placehold.it/100" alt="" />
        <div class="infobox"><div class="inner">    
    </div>
```

Comment: @JonathanAlexander edited, it's just a matter of changing to the appropriate src again and playing with the top and left values.

Comment: it's behind the headerpic now, how could i move it into the front?

Comment: @JonathanAlexander A) swap the headerpic class or the src around on the elements, I may have got that mixed up since your original HTML was a bit broken. B) set a high `z-index` on the thing you want to be in front.

Comment: i already tried this, but then the whole content: Menu, Page content and !image in the footer! moves upwards. Means content isn't  visible Menu is on the Picture and in mobile it's a mess.. Sadly.. Take a look at it. I'll demonstrate it http://zgraggen-zahnarzt.ch/

Comment: @RadoHinn It worked with a small re-construction of your solution. But if i go on smaller devices, it covers my menu now. It should move to the left top and get a bit smaller. How can i add this effect in my style?

Comment: Now, you need to learn media querys and write them to reposition. I reccommend [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries) for starters.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not actually tested this but, if it works thumbs up. I forget to complete my css classes and goes to php and not I have full knowledge of php

```
margin-left: 25%;
margin-top:25%;
```

Answer (score 0):

Increase the z-index, case may be that your logo has more z index than img divs

Comment: I haven't set any z index yet:
     '.header img.headerpic  { 
      max-width:100%; 
    float:left; 
    position:relative;
    background:transparent url(../images/header.jpg)
}
.header img.logo { 
    position: relative; 
    float:left; 
    max-width:100%;  
    background:transparent url(../images/logo.png )
}'

Comment: Then make header img.headerpic relative and .header img.logo absolute, by this .header img.logo will come over the  img.headerpic relative div

Comment: I already tried it, but changed it like you recommended. Still doensn't work

Answer (score 0):

If you want both images to stack on top of each other, what you need to do is to set header as **relative** and img to **absolute** like so:

```css
.header{
  position: relative;
 }

.header img{
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
    <img class="imgA1" src="https://placehold.it/200/333333">
    <img class="imgB1" src="https://placehold.it/100">
</div>
```

By setting both `img.headerpic` and `img.logo` to `position:relative`, both will occupy their own space and thus won't stack on top of each other.

By defining the parent's position as **relative**, in this case `.header`, anything inside `.header` with an `img` tag that's positioned absolute will occupy the same space, relative to the parent.

Comment: Issiue with your code, my logo disappears behind the headerpic, had that Problem before already.

Comment: set z-index for respective classes. in this case since you want the logo to appear on top, set a higher z-index for it. so .header img.logo { z-index: 5; }

Comment: Tried to add the z-index but still no "reaction" the image is still behind my headerpic. Plus the menu slided to the top too, and in mobile everything looks kinda awkward now= Menu not visible, body right after the headerpic and logo 2px visible behind header

Comment: would it be easier if i would give you Access to the files?

Comment: if i can look at the files, that would help, yes

Comment: leave your email in the comment. I'm onine and will give you the details

Comment: you can reach me at contact@demirose.me